# 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'verbose_name' error after searching

Tags: django, search

I have an app where I created a relation between Offer and the Contractor in the Offer model:

```
contractor = models.ForeignKey(Contractor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Everything works fine except one thing. When I am trying to search through Contractors model using verbose name, I am receiving an Atributeerror:
'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'verbose_name'

Searching code below (contractors/views.py):

```
    def get(self,request):
        contractors = self.model.objects.all()

        if 'search' in request.GET:
            search_for = request.GET['search']
            if search_for is not '':
                filter = request.GET['filterSelect']
                search_in = [field.name for field in Contractor._meta.get_fields() if field.verbose_name==filter]
                kwargs = {'{0}__{1}'.format(search_in[0], 'contains'): search_for}
                contractors = self.model.objects.all().filter(**kwargs)
```

Why Am I receiving and error if searching is performed on Constructor model and Constructor model have no fields related to Offer model? 
How can I fix that? Or how to create searching bar where user can choose where to search from drop down list containing all verbose names of the model fields?

Contractor model:

```
class Contractor(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField("nazwa", max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField("telefon", max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField("e-mail")
    website = models.CharField("www", max_length=100)
    NIP = models.CharField("NIP", max_length=50)
    REGON = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    KRS = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField("miasto", max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notes = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('contractors:list', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Answer (score 3):

because you did not set a `verbose_name`

```
 contractor = models.ForeignKey(Contractor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Contractor Details')
```

But the question is why you want to search for the verbose_name anyway. What is it that list comprehension `search_in` is supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to create a drop down list with verbose names. User could choose the field in which he would search for the entered word. I wanted to use verbose because these names look better than the model field names. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: could you add the Contractor model?

Comment: I updated my first post and add Constructor model to it.